# Replace from nth occurrence of pattern till the end of line with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

For example:

```
/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten
```

Need to delete after the 6th occurrence of '/', including itself:

```
/some/long/path/we/need
```

Using sed I came up with this solution, but it's kind of workaround-ish:

```
path=/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten
slashesToKeep=5
n=2+slashesToKeep
echo $path | sed "s/[^/]*//$n;s/\/\/.*//g"
```

Cleaner solution much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Input**

```
/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten
```

**Code**

**Cut Solution**

```
echo '/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten' | cut -d '/' -f 1-6
```

**AWK Solution**

```
echo '/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten' | awk -F '/'  '{ for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {print $i} }' | tr '\n' '/'|sed 's/.$//'
```

**Output**

```
/some/long/path/we/need
```

Comment: for awk, use the inbuilt variables to modify the output, instead of depending on others. `echo '/some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten' | awk -v j=6 'BEGIN{RS="/";ORS="/"} {if(i<j) print $1;i++; if(i==j) {ORS="\n";print $1}}'` does the same trick, but it comes nowhere near the cut solution

Comment: +1 for the cut solution. If I were you I'd delete the awk+tr+sed solution.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\/[^\/]*//6g' file
```

Comment: why not use a different delimiter and simplify it to `sed 's#/[^/]*##6g'`

Comment: Thanks for the sed solution!

Answer (score 2):

Awk:

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{NF=6}1'
```

In action:

```
$ echo /some/long/path/we/need/to/shorten | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{NF=6}1' 
/some/long/path/we/need
```